# Create Multiple Objects in a loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop, object

I'm a beginner and was researching to find out if you can grab a name from an array to then put that name as the name of the object in a for loop.

The code a specifically created for this question is represented below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class YourMum{
    public:
        string name;

        YourMum(string aName){
            name = aName;
        }
};

int main()
{
    string names[5] = {"Jeremy_Clarkson", "Boris_Johnson", "Vladmir_Putin", "Peter_Griffin", "MeAndYourMum"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        YourMum names[i];

        cout << names[i].name << endl;
        cout << "You are great if you answer my question!";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about your code? Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: From one of the comments on an answer, it looks like you are hoping to create a variable _named_ `Jeremy_Clarkson` _from_ the string so you can do `Jeremy_Clarkson.name`. If that's what you're asking, then **no**, you cannot do this -- as C++ is statically typed, and you can't materialize new symbol names from string literals

Comment: Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's not clear what you're trying to do, but you've got a few things that aren't a good idea.

First, you defined `string names[5]` and then inside loop you hid `names` by making a second variable with the same name. While that's legal, it's a bad practice.

Second, you're using the second one (`YourMum names`) illegally:

1. You declared it as length `i` (using a non-standard feature of the compiler) but then reference element `i`. The elements of an array of length `i` range from `0..i-1`, so `[i]` is one element past the end.
2. And you haven't initialized it anyway.

I'm not really clear what you're trying to do, so I can't even provide example code of how to do it.

Comment: Since YourMum isn't default constructible you can't have a raw array of them. My _guess_ is that something like a `std::vector<YourMum>` with some calls like `mums.emplace_back(names[i])` would do what the asker wants? But I also can't tell what behavior is actually desired.

Answer (score 0):

The `YourMum` class you have shown is not default constructible, so `YourMum names[size];` will not work.  Every object of `YourMum` needs to be passed a parameter in order to create it.  You can use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) for that, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

class YourMum{
    public:
        string name;

        YourMum(string aName){
            name = aName;
        }
};

int main()
{
    string names[5] = {"Jeremy_Clarkson", "Boris_Johnson", "Vladmir_Putin", "Peter_Griffin", "MeAndYourMum"};

    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(YourMum), alignof(YourMum)>::type arr[5];
    YourMum *mums = reinterpret_cast<YourMum*>(arr);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        new (&mums[i]) YourMum(names[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << mums[i].name << endl;
        cout << "You are great if you answer my question!";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mums[i].~YourMum();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can use `std::vector` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class YourMum{
    public:
        string name;

        YourMum(string aName){
            name = aName;
        }
};

int main()
{
    string names[5] = {"Jeremy_Clarkson", "Boris_Johnson", "Vladmir_Putin", "Peter_Griffin", "MeAndYourMum"};

    std::vector<YourMum> mums;
    mums.reserve(5);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mums.emplace_back(names[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << mums[i].name << endl;
        cout << "You are great if you answer my question!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should rename the name variable to something like _name or name_ for lisibility (to differenciate it from variables that aren't in the class), and you should also use the private section of your class to declare it and use getters/setters functions to edit it. Secondly, in your code you are declaring the object inside a loop, so it will get destroyed as soon as the loop iterates again, so if you want to create n objects in a loop and interact with them after you should either use a container class (like std::vector) or use a default constructor (which is better). Here is an updated version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class YourMum
{
    public:

    YourMum(void) : _name() { }
    YourMum(std::string name) : _name(name) { }

    std::string getName(void) const { return _name; }
    void setName(std::string name) { _name = name; }


    private:

    std::string _name;
};

int main()
{
    std::string names[5] = { "Jeremy_Clarkson", "Boris_Johnson", "Vladmir_Putin", "Peter_Griffin", "MeAndYourMum" };
    YourMum mums[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        mums[i].setName(names[i]);
        std::cout << mums[i].getName() << std::endl
        << "You are great if you answer my question!" << std::endl;
    }
    // this way you can still access mums here if you want to
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to access to a class by it's name as index what you can also do is using std::map like this

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::string names[5] = { "Jeremy_Clarkson", "Boris_Johnson", "Vladmir_Putin", "Peter_Griffin", "MeAndYourMum" };
    std::map <std::string, YourMum> mums;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        mums[names[i]] = YourMum(names[i]);
    std::cout << mums["Jeremy_Clarkson"].getName() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
> for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
>         YourMum name(names[i]);
> 
>         cout << name.name << endl;
>         cout << "You are great if you answer my question!";
>     }
```

Comment: Can I access the values of the objects in a way like... cout << Jeremy_Clarkson.name

Comment: @GeneralFishy Variable names are statically typed. They need to actually be named at compile-time. You can't make a look through strings and turn them into variable names, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: @GeneralFishy If you have something like `YourMum mums[]` (see my answer for an example), then you can do `YourMum &Jeremy_Clarkson = mums[0];` and then `Jeremy_Clarkson.name` will work.